# Overlaying Image ontop of FontAwesomeIcon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am designing a personal website and I wanted to use Font-Awesome Icons. Unfortunately, Font-Awesome doesn't have every single icon and I wanted a python icon. I have downloaded a python icon separately from a different source and I want to place this image on top of a font awesome icon.

This is an image of how I did this when both the icons were from Font-Awesome:

[Please click here to see how I would like this to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XND91.png)

Could you please help by telling me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FontAwesome provides a class `fa-stack` to overlap two icons. try this,

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" class=" fa-stack-1x" style="width: 100%;opacity: 0.5;">
</span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Oh I thought you could only do that with Font-Awesome Icons. Thanks!